# Avoiding same users on each day in MySQL Birthday processing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table which has date of birth column for users and I want to know the users who is having birthdays falling in the next 7 days.

I have no issues in this. I have done that using the below query.

```
SELECT userId,
       DATE_ADD(dobValue, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dobValue) YEAR)
  FROM users
 WHERE dobValue is not null
   AND DATE_ADD(dobValue, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dobValue) YEAR) 
       BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

My question here is when I run the SQL today, it will fetch the list of users having birthdays in the next 7 days. If I the SQL again tomorrow, it will fetch the same users as the condition of 7 days gets satisfied.

I don't want the same users to be listed again for processing each day.

How better this SQL can be changed for this?

**SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a294/1**

Comment: i guess the easiest way would be running the script once a week only, otherwise if you run it today and tomorrow, tomorrow you would only get results for one day.

Comment: It will be a problem when a new user signs tomorrow. That user's DOB will never be captured as the next cron job runs after 7 days as per your advice.

Comment: Run the query every day with a time horizon of one day.

Comment: I considered that before.. but the purpose of the script is to let other users know about the DOB in advance instead of adding on same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table to store the alerted userids that you can clean once a month or so:

```
create table alerted(userId int, alertedDate timestamp);
```

Then you do your query validating that table:

```
SELECT userId,
  DATE_ADD(dobValue, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(dobValue) YEAR) 'date'
FROM users
WHERE dobValue IS NOT NULL
  AND DATE_ADD(dobValue, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(dobValue) YEAR) 
             BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND userId NOT IN (
    SELECT userId
    FROM alerted
    );
```

But in the same Job you do:

```
INSERT INTO alerted
SELECT userId,
  now()
FROM users
WHERE dobValue IS NOT NULL
  AND DATE_ADD(dobValue, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(dobValue) YEAR) 
         BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND userId NOT IN (
    SELECT userId
    FROM alerted
    );
```

This way, the same userId only will be "alerted" once.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b1b7/1)</kbd>

Other option would be to have the date of signing up to the service on that table and factor that in the query, instead of having a different table.

Comment: I believe there should be some other simpler way than this.

Comment: You could consider the date of signing up for the service and check if it is after you run the last job, you enter that one too to the records returned.

Comment: Thats a good idea.. +1.. but this table has only DOB and not DOJ column.

Comment: I added that to the answer, so you can +1 the answer :p. Can't you modify the table to add the DOJ?

Comment: I don't have control on that. I did +1 for you last comment :)

Comment: Then i think your best option would be the table i mention in my answer. Because you have to feed something to the query that tells you what users were already alerted.

Comment: @Purus. But do you have a table with the DOJ? You can always JOIN with that table to get the users that signed up in the last day

Comment: I like to avoid that due to perfomance as the main table will have several thousand rows and this one will be very less.

Comment: If you have indexes on the joining columns that is not a performance issue, but it's an idea.